# Overwhelming the Eng. management system, is there specific course of action to recover faster

Tags: engine, cel, electronic-control-module, citroen, citroen-c4

Citroen C4 2005, Petrol, UK

Yesterday I managed to overwhelm my car (for the second time I've been having it, first time was about half an year go). What happened was I was at a rather busy stop traffic, trying to make a right. I did at least 30 KMh on first gear, maybe even more, with quite the steep acceleration (pretty much the same thing I did the first time). What was the outcome (apart from making the right as desired) was I overwhelmed my Engine Management System, and having the SERVICE light come on, as well as "Engine management system faulty" board computer warning. This then led to my speed limiter disabling as well (I use it more often than my head lights).

Now I know that I shouldn't have let this happen in the first place, but **is there something I can do, after the fault occurred to help the system recover faster ?**

Leaving the car overnight helped my speed limiter come back online, and as far as I can remember, the entire thing cleared in few days, when it first happened, but for the now I still get the warning and the SERVICE light is still on.

Comment: Have you read the codes to see exactly the issue?

Comment: What is a "speed limiter"? Do you mean a rev limiter, which disrupts the ignition if the engine speed gets too high? Sorry if that's a stupid question, but that's an unfamiliar term and I wouldn't think a rev limiter would stop working.

Comment: TMN: The Citroen C4 does, indeed, have a Speed Limiter. It's a drive-by-wire car, and there is a dashboard setting which can be used to set a speed that you do not wish the car to exceed. If you try to exceed that speed, you can push the accelerator as much as you like, but the car won't go any faster. There is also an Overspeed warning, which sounds an alarm if you go over a set maximum speed, but it won't stop you going faster.

Comment: `overwhelm my car` ? Er, just no.  Accelerated the car to red-line condition on the tachometer, much more likely.  That engine doesn't like to go 7000, 8000 or 9000 rpm.  Things get weird at that speed.  Alternator? Air Conditioning? Water Pump? Oil pressure?  Injector solenoid speeds?  All of those things are direct drive related to crankshaft speed.  Did you overwhelm the processor in the engine computer?  I seriously doubt it.  No manufacturer is going to release a computer with marginal clock/ computing processing times. That just doesn't make sense. Not enough fuel pressure = more likely.

Comment: Close due to lack of response to comments from OP after two months?

Comment: @dlu Apart from paulster, the rest is a speed limiter related discussion and a bunch of rhetorical questions, don't have much to add on that. There were no codes so decided to leave that question unanswered.

Comment: The ECU set no codes? That seems strange. I'm not familiar with that car, so I'm curious about the lights. Is the service light a "change my oil" thing, or is is what we call the "check engine light" (CEL) in the US. The CEL indicates that the ECU has set a DTC (diagnostic trouble code).

Comment: @dlu yep, no codes, the "Service" would translate into a "Check engine" yes, and am still yet to figure out what exactly's going on.